# SDL2 problems with webp animated images works with gifs but not with webp

Tags: c++, sdl-2, webp, sdl-image, animated-webp

im trying to play animated image to SDL2, my code works with animated gifs and static, if i add a static webp image works fine to, but if i add an animated webp, console gives me message fail to decode.
I get the SDL2 last release with libwebp-7.dll, then i compiled webp to get libs and dlls libwebpdecoder.dll/lib and libwebpdemux.dll/lib, i dont know if i have wrong name of dlls as i get libwebp.dll and sdl_image release has libwebp-7.dll.

I´m using VS2019, i try compile using website example and vs2019 console.

i dont know if is need compile sdl_image with external options, and if so dont know how compile it to add webp/extra (folder with sdl code files) on windows.

```
#include <SDL.h> 
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <decode.h>
#include <demux.h>
#include "SDL_endian.h"

SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;
IMG_Animation* anim;
SDL_Texture** textures;

//anim = IMG_LoadAnimation("logo.gif");  // works for animated gif our static
anim = IMG_LoadAnimation("anim.webp"); // works for static but for
```

CONSOLE MESSAGE :  Couldn't load Failed to decode WEBP: �w♥☺

Comment: Q: What is the exact error message???  Please [Edit] your post.  Q: Have you been able to independently verify that the .webp is valid?  For example, does your file render correctly in MS Edge?  Q: Have you tried other, different .webp files with your SDL?  *EDUCATED GUESS*: You probably have a valid file ... but it's probably a version that your libraries don't support yet.  You'll need to do more troubleshooting to confirm this guess...

Comment: Alredy edited, i take the images from -- https://cloudinary.com/blog/animated_webp_how_to_convert_animated_gif_to_webp_and_save_up_to_90_bandwidth  -- tryed more than one diferente include from outher website, i think i need compile  SDL_image with webp animated options, but im not figuring out how to do it, webp libary has an extra folder with sdl files. i really lost, Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the exact error message - it helps. Source code for the WebP loader is here: github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL_image/blob/master/IMG_webp.c. It looks like it's successfully reading the file info ... but fails here: `if ( features.has_alpha ) ret = lib.WebPDecodeRGBAInto() else ret = WebPDecodeRGBInto()`.  I don't think there's anything wrong with your "build".  It looks like the libraries you're using simply don't seem to support the files you're reading.

Comment: Thanks, is strange because it has WebP animation functions in https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/blob/main/IMG_webp.c, as so in IMG_gif.c, I get the show anime.c as example to do my code. Oki, after read the source sdl_image.h found in line 2042 that the support for now is only for gif. Thanks I think we have to wait for new support hope soon as problably future is WebP format. Thanks again